# How to add numbers from items in an array of objects in Javascript to output to a table

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, calculated-columns

This is the array: Data from year:

```
[{"Years":2023,"New":305,"Updates":360},
 {"Years":2022,"New":334,"Updates":467},
 {"Years":2021,"New":272,"Updates":502},
 {"Years":2020,"New":291,"Updates":377},
 {"Years":2019,"New":327,"Updates":365}]
```

I have working code to create a table of Year, New, Updates and Total.

```html
<tbody>
{parsedAdmin2ReportData.map((row, index) => (
  <tr key={index}>
    <td>{row.Years}</td>
    <td>{row.New}</td>
    <td>{row.Updates}</td>
    <td>{row.New + row.Updates}</td>
    <td>{parsedAdmin2ReportData[index].New}</td>
  </tr>
))}
</tbody>
```

I want to add another column that shows the YoY % change but can't get the value of the previous year

For example for 2023 the YoY Change formula would be `((row New of 2022 + row Updates of 2022) -(row New + row Updates))/(row New of 2022 + row Updates of 2022)`

The number would show as a percentage Value, red if negative and green if positive.
There would be no calculation for the 2019 row.

I thought I could navigate the index like `parsedAdmin2ReportData[index-1].New`

but that did not work. I also tried index — and it did not work. Is there a way to get the values in the table and run mathematical functions on them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: (offtopic) Why it's "Years" (plural) if it just accepts ***one*** year? And why the first uppercase?

Comment: `parsedAdmin2ReportData[index-1].New` should work. Just make sure you don't do it in the first row, when `index==0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some additional computations within your map function.

```js
<tbody>
{parsedAdmin2ReportData.map((row, index, arr) => ({
  let yoy = "";
  if (index < arr.length - 1) { // it's not the last row
    let nextRow = arr[index + 1]; // get the next row
    let nextTot = nextRow.New + nextRow.Updates;
    let diff = (nextTot - (row.New + row.Updates)) / nextTot;
    yoy = diff.toFixed(2) + "%"; // or whatever format
  }
  
  return <tr key={index}>
    <td>{row.Years}</td>
    <td>{row.New}</td>
    <td>{row.Updates}</td>
    <td>{row.New + row.Updates}</td>
    <td>{parsedAdmin2ReportData[index].New}</td>
    <td>{yoy}</td>
  </tr>
}
))}
</tbody>
```